# В Windows7 не работает проект, собранный в QT

Tags: windows, qt

Есть проект [SmartDeblur](https://github.com/Y-Vladimir/SmartDeblur), очень нужно скомпилировать и запустить его.
В QT я не силен, поставил себе на комп QT 3.0.1(написано в справке, что основан на 5.2.1)(Qt Creator 3.0.1 for Windows (66 MB) (Info)) и это еще поставил(Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2010, 235 MB) (Info)), всё брал отсюда [link](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

Огромнейшая проблема: проект не запускается в windows.

Ругался, что не находит заголовочные файлы типа такого: Qapplication, решил проблему(прописал руками все пути: K:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets*)
Теперь ругается на #include "ui_HelpDialog.h" и на #include "ui_MainWindow.h".

Чего только не делал, уже не припомню. Даже пошел собирать проект в Ubunt-е. Т.к. я в ubuntu не силен, то это вызвало еще большие проблемы. Пишет что нет такого файла или директории. В каталоге с программой их и нет, есть: HelpDialog.ui и MainWindow.ui. Но автор программы не просто же так их вписал. Пробовал переименовывать, не помогает. Что же тут не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про [портирование приложений на qt5](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164721/) или настройте с какой версией собирать, вы явно задействовали 5-ю. По поводу недостающих файлов - qt это строго говоря не библиотека языка с++, а надстройка над ним, именно по этому при билде проектов добавляется еще один шаг - запуск qmake, который и переводит ваш код в то что способен съесть компилятор, если вы влезете в папку сборки вместо папки исходников то скорее всего найдете недостающие файлы.

Comment: Это не qt предлагает, это ide qt creator, не путайте их. И когда он предлагает он обычно выводит все имеющиеся и известные ему сдк предлагая вам выбрать с каким именно вы хотите собирать, читайте внимательней

Comment: Чтож так мудрено всё( Сейчас поставлю то что noskriptt предложил, может заработает...

Comment: Оп, ээээ, пока устанавливается QT 4.8.5, а в чем не совместимость версий? в каком файле эта несовместимость кроется? У меня при компиляции вылетала куча ошибок когда вроде как файл формы инклудил так: #include"form_name.ui"

Comment: несовместимость в том что виджеты перенесли в отдельный модуль. Я же дал ссылку - там все написано

Comment: Прочел статью с хабра. Что-то уяснил, но что сразу поймешь, когда QT впервые видишь... Поставил это: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw.exe   QT по прежнему просит настроить проект, просит указать путь импортирования сборки... Что ему нужно? Как со сборкой поступить, откуда ее взять? Что такое сборка? На скольуо я понял, это поможет http://habrahabr.ru/post/152377/ ???

Comment: Нет, не поможет, это статическая сборка вообще не при чем. Забейте на импортирование сборки, у вас над нею должно быть перечисление установленых комплектов, выберите из них Desktop qt 4.8.5 mingw 4.8 (или что-то типа того, у меня не стоит 4.8) и нажмите настроить проект

Answer (score 0):

Старая версия qt. в руководстве сказано использовать 4 ветку.
И не стоило ставить 5 ветку данной qt. Поставь именно 4 версию. Вот http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw.exe

Comment: наоборот новая, ТС просто перепутал версию среды qt creator с версией самой библиотеки

Comment: не, все возможно... Но смотри... "K:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets*" явно 5 ветка указана. да еще и под сборку в студийке 2010.

Comment: я не понял твой ответ просто, т.к. ты не уточнил что старая ветка нужна проекту, а ТС упорно путает среду (которая вообще не обязательна для сборки) с самой библиотекой, думал Старая версия qt. означает что у тс установлена старая ветка